# Relationships between C++ objects

Tags: c++, relationship

I have a vector of journeys and a vector of locations. A journey is between two places.

```
struct Data {
  std::vector<Journey> m_journeys;
  std::vector<Locations> m_locations;
};
struct Journey {
  ?? m_startLocation;
  ?? m_endLocation;
};
```

How can I create the relationship between each journey and two locations?

I thought I could just store references/pointers to the start and end locations, however if more locations are added to the vector, then it will reallocate storage and move all the locations elsewhere in memory, and then the pointers to the locations will point to junk.

I could store the place names and then search the list in Data, but that would require keeping a reference to Data (breaking encapsulation/SRP), and then a not so efficient search.

I think if all the objects were created on the heap, then shared_ptr could be used, (so Data would contain `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Journey>>`), then this would work? (it would require massive rewrite so avoiding this would be preferable)

Is there some C++/STL feature that is like a pointer but abstracts away/is independent of memory location (or order in the vector)?

Comment: You could use indices

Comment: @DieterLücking, this would break if Locations were removed/added. (I'd have to go through all the Journeys and update the indexes which sounds messy)

Comment: You cold use a container that does not invalidate reference/pointer/iterators on insertion(almost any node type structure comes to mind)

Answer (score 2):

I'd say make a `vector<shared_ptr<Location>>`for your index of locations, and Journey would contain two `weak_ptr<Location>`.

```
struct Data {
    std::vector<Journey> m_journeys;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Location>> m_locations;
};

struct Journey {
    std::weak_ptr<Location> m_startLocation;
    std::weak_ptr<Location> m_endLocation;
};
```

[std::weak_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) can dangle and that's exactly what you want. :)

The concern is that one could access a Journey containing a deleted Location. A weak pointer provides an `expired()` method that can tell you if the data of the parent shared pointer (that would be in your  `m_locations` vector) still exists.

Accessing data from a weak pointer is safe, and will require the use of the `lock()` method.

Here is a great example of how one usually uses a weak pointer:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/lock

Comment: Thanks, why couldn't I use a shared_ptr in the Journey too?

Comment: Hello @Jonathan. You definitely _could_ use a vector of ```shared_ptr``` to store your Journeys. It only didn't seem _required_ judging from your code sample. If you end up needing shared ownership on a Journey (for instance, a user has a list of trips he has made), then you would definitely consider using a smart pointer.
Let me know if you want me to elaborate on this matter.

Comment: Ah sorry I meant use shared_ptr instead of weak_ptr in the Journey struct.

Comment: Ah, that is a pertinent questions! Both are valid and the final decision depends on the behavior you want. With my proposal, if you delete a ```Location``` from ```Data```, then all the journeys that contain said location would then hold _"safe"_ invalid pointers (printing it would display _"journey to unknown location"_). In this situation, ```Data``` sort of has the upper hand, because it can end the lifetime of a Location for everyone else.  I believe it sort of keeps your data _consistent_. (1/2)

Comment: Simply think about your data and _what it means to delete a Location_. You could have an equally shared ownership between ```Data``` and ```Journey``` (aka "```shared_ptr``` on both sides") because you don't mind keeping old locations in your program. I gave you a solution that _seemed more appropriate to me_, but I cannot anticipate what your actual requirements will be in the end. _That_ is your job. :) (2/2)

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't any "C++/STL feature that is like a pointer but abstracts away/is independent of memory location".

That answers that.

This is simply not the right set of containers for such a relationship between classes. You have to pick the appropriate container for your objects first, instead of selecting some arbitrary container first, and then trying to figure out how to make it work with your relationship.

Using a vector of `std::shared_ptr`s would be one option, just need to watch out for circular references. Another option would be to use `std::list` instead of `std::vector`, since `std::list` does not reallocate when it grows.

If each `Locations` instance has a unique identifier of some kind, using a `std::map`, and then using that location identifier to refer to a location, and then looking it up in the map. Although a `std::map` also doesn't reallocate upon growth, the layer of indirection offers some value as well.